# gcc: undefined reference to function

Tags: linux, gcc

I know there have been many similar questions, but I have no choice but to post this question because I have not found an answer to my problem even after hours of googling. I'd appreciate your understanding.

I linked with gcc as follows.

```
gcc myprogram.c csapp.c -o a.out
```

csapp.c defines the functions used in myprogram.c. Myprogram.c is including csapp.h.

The following error is occurring:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `Pthread_create':
csapp.c:(.text+0x121e): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `Pthread_cancel':
csapp.c:(.text+0x1257): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `Pthread_join':
csapp.c:(.text+0x129b): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `Pthread_detach':
csapp.c:(.text+0x12d4): undefined reference to `pthread_detach'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `Pthread_once':
csapp.c:(.text+0x1343): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `Sem_init':
csapp.c:(.text+0x1370): undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `P':
csapp.c:(.text+0x139f): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIWxAk3.o: in function `V':
csapp.c:(.text+0x13ce): undefined reference to `sem_post'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These are definitely defined in csapp.c. Why do these errors occur?

Comment: You are defining `sem_post`, `sem_init`, etc. in your application code?  That is a huge mistake.  You should not re-implement basic functionality.  Perhaps when you say "These are definitely defined in csapp.c" you mean that csapp.c included the header files that provide the declarations.  Those functions should absolutely *not* be defined in csapp.c

Comment: But including the declarations is not sufficient.  Header files are not libraries.  You have *not* told the linker where to find the definitions.  Hence the error.

Comment: "These are definitely defined": There is a very important distinction in C between *declaring* a function `void foo(int x, int y);` which only informs the compiler of the function's return types and argument so that the compiler knows how to generate code to call it; and *defining* a function `void foo(int x, int y) { /* code code code */ }` which contains the code of the function itself.  The standard header files contain only the *declarations*.  The *definitions* were used when the library itself was compiled; now you have to link with it to actually access that compiled code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compile and link with `-pthread`